# Can I use a Prior with Simulated data?

Tags: bayesian, prior, beta-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution

I have a prior about some proportion that follows a Beta distribution. Unfortunately, I do not have (yet) observed data but I was offered a thousand simulated datasets.

Each dataset comes from simulating a mixed effects model and produces an outcome for 500 individuals (0/1). The data to fit the model are taken from another similar experimental study.

I was thinking if it is possible to update the prior according to the likelihood for each simulated dataset (in a Beta-Binomial framework) and then some how "combine" the resulting 1000 possible posteriors. I have never seen something like this though. I know that combining Beta distributions is not that straightforward. There is a similar question posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240278/probability-distribution-to-represent-group-mean-of-multiple-beta-distributions) but the posterior is known a priori which simplifies things.

Comment: The main issue is about the meaning of these simulated datasets. Which distribution are they simulated from? How does it relate to the true (data-generating) value of the proportion?

Comment: Thanks. I will add clarification